# Update of a specific property in the list of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of `dataArray` objects

I want to associate TextInput with a specific object in this list.

Every change of text must also change the `dataArray` in `state`

How to do it correctly? The code below does not work

```
export default class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dataArray: this.props.dataArray
    };
  }

  _renderContent = section => {
    let arrayIdx = this.state.dataArray.findIndex(
      x => x.title == section.title
    );
    return (
      <TextInput
        value={this.state.dataArray[arrayIdx].content}
        onChangeText={con =>
          this.setState({
            dataArray: update(this.state.dataArray, {
              arrayIdx: { content: { $set: con } }
            })
          })
        }
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content padder>
          <Accordion
            dataArray={this.state.dataArray}
            renderContent={this._renderContent}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `It doesnt work` mean? Do you get any helpful errors? Does your pc start burning?

Comment: First i would suggest to make an external component for the accordionSection. I mean `_renderContent ` should be an external component, a wrapper for the `TextInput`, and then imported here. Second, `onChangeText` should also be a separate function in your `TextInputWrapper` component, not an inline function. Yes, this would need some refactoring but your code would be cleaner, easier to understand and maybe would solve your problem ( which we don't know what it is )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are literally updating `arrayIdx` instead of the index that it refers to. You need to use a [Computed Property Name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) like `[arrayIdx]`.

```
[arrayIdx]: { content: { $set: con } }
```